# Kendo Grid: using model.set to update the value of required fields triggers validation error

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a Kendo Grid using a custom popup editor. One of the fields is a Kendo dropdownlist which uses a remote datasource.

When a user makes a selection the data associated with the selected item is used to update a couple of the other fields in the popup editor using `model.set`.

This is working well: the model and the field are updated.

However, if I then add `required validationMessage="This field is required"` to the fields being updated by `model.set` the validation error is triggered and the fields are not updated.

I've setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matbeard/ZPuS8/7/) to demonstrate the problem. In this case, the ProductName in the custom popup editor can be set by clicking the `Set Product` button. You'll notice the validation error is triggered, but if you remove the `required` attribute from the field it is updated correctly.

Is this a bug? Why is the validation error being triggered when the value is being set?

Edit: just to clarify -- this is when adding new records, not editing existing ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you assign a value to `ProductName` you are actually losing focus from the `input`, that triggers the validation and makes it complain about leaving it empty.

The solution would be assigning first the value to the `input` and then do the `set`.

```
var win = $(this).closest("[data-role=window]");
var uid = win.data("uid");
var input = $("[name='ProductName']", win); 
// Assign value (anything works)
input.val("Test Product");
var model = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.getByUid(uid);
model.set('ProductName','Test Product');
```

Your Fiddle modified here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZPuS8/8/

Comment: Hi Onabai. Thanks for that. I'd actually noticed I could do that before, but was hoping it wouldn't be necessary as I use this technique extensively (and was hoping to avoid doubling-up on the code). I'm still not 100% sure why it happens, since the input being assigned a value doesn't have focus in the first place. Anyway, I guess it won't take too long to go through and add the extra lines.